# Word-wrap in a table-cell

Tags: html, css

I want a table that uses all the screen if necessary but does break words if they get too long.

I tried:

```
<table width=100%>
    <tr><td class=breaklines>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     
    </td></tr>
</table>

.breaklines
{
      word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

It does not work, the words in the table-cell are never broken.

So how to break the words in a table-cell?

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9u0pj3hn/

Answer (score 4):

There's a interesting trick that works for table cells, and it works for text-overflow too. It's including max-width like this:

See it working: https://jsfiddle.net/9u0pj3hn/1/

```
.breaklines
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width:0;
}
```

Comment: There are two more suitable ways to do that without hacking and tricking.

Comment: This works for this purpose and more purposes like text overflow. The only way to solve this problem is this and table layout

Comment: `word-break: break-all` or `table-layout: fixed` are quite good and not tricky.

Comment: Break all is not good, is good for a developer mind but not for a designer mind. Op said that break all is not a solution. My solution is not a hack, is 100% valid and recommended by David Walsh

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result by using `break-all`. Hence if you write you code

```
<td style="word-break:break-all;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
```

or

```
<span style="word-break:break-all;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</span>
```

Then it will work.
See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/9kmmqphx/

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can also used this solution.

```css
table{
    width: 100%; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table width=100%>
    <tr><td class=breaklines>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `table-layout` to `fixed`.

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

```css
table.breaklines
{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.breaklines
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table class="breaklines">
    <tr><td class="breaklines">   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

U need to set the width of the `<td>` in order let HTML know where to break the word.
For example:

```
<td style="width:50px;">AAAAAA</td>
```

Comment: It won't help you because of `table-layout` property default value – `auto`.